# Is there any guide how to train a Microsoft custom MT engine and deploy it on Azure?

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator, machine-translation, bing-translator-api

I have a big parallel corpus in TMX format which I'd like to use for training a custom Microsoft MT engine in the Microsoft Translator Hub. Then, I'd like to deploy this trained MT engine on Azure and use it in a cloud-based CAT tool.
Is there any step-by-step guide how to do that?

Comment: This question is off-topic as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

- You upload your TMX to the Hub, and you train, optimize and deploy
  your MT engine.
- The Hub overview page lists a category ID with each
  of your trained systems.
- You copy the category ID from the Hub overview page into the "category" field that your CAT tool's MT connector exposes.

If your CAT tool does not expose a "category" field in the connector, please ask the CAT tool vendor to add it. In the Translator API call it is simply an additional parameter in the call, that allows the service to find your custom trained system when translating.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris!